# Wifi LED continuously blinking UBUNTU 14.04 and slowed connection

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I can connect to my wifi fine, but when it is connected the led light to indicate if I am connected to the network keeps blinking. When I disconnect it stays solid. My network is hidden and has a MAC filter. I also want to add that I contacted my internet provider and ruled out them as a problem. Because my connection is 45 Mb/s wired but 16 Mb/s wireless. Where as when I had Windows 7 my average wireless speed was between 35 Mb/s and 40 Mb/s

Here is a summary of some of my specs on my hp pavilion dv6000

Processor 
Processors Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz 800.00MHz Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz 800.00MHz Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz 800.00MHz Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz 800.00MHz

Network
Interfaces Network Interfaces eth0 0.00MiB 0.00MiB lo 0.11MiB 0.11MiB virbr0 0.00MiB 0.00MiB wlan0 3.61MiB 0.69MiB -Computer- Processor : 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz Memory : 3994MB (1391MB used) Operating System : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS User Name : john (John Syzemore) Date/Time : Sun 20 Apr 2014 12:37:24 AM MST -Display- Resolution : 1366x768 pixels OpenGL Renderer : Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile X11 Vendor : The X.Org Foundation -Multimedia- Audio Adapter : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH -

Input Devices- Lid Switch Power Button Power Button AT Translated Set 2 keyboard Razer Razer Naga Hex Razer Razer Naga Hex HP TrueVision HD SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad Video Bus HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm : 3= HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone HDA Intel PCH Mic ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer HP WMI hotkeys -Printers (CUPS)- HP-Officejet-4620-series : *Default* -SCSI Disks- ATA Hitachi HTS54755 hp DVD-RAM UJ8B1

Comment: What is the issue here; that you do not like the blinking lights when connected?

Comment: I guess I'm not used to it since it never did that before on windows. I rather fix the wifi issue over that I'd I had to choose

Comment: Fair enough, but I would suggest you rephrase the question such that you ask how you would go about changing the behaviour of the blinking lights, just so it is clear to other users what you wish to accomplish. Otherwise; it looks like you got an answer :)

Comment: @RevRend80 Can you post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`. The question lacks relevant info about the wireless card, and, on the other hand, is overloaded with irrelevant data. We don't need to know what printer you use to help with the blinking wifi led.

Comment: Having the same issue as you also, Blinking lights and slow wifi speeds ever since new install of 14.04. The terminal commands above also fixed my blinking lights, Now its about speeding that wifi up a bit....

Answer (score 5):

This helped me to get rid off blinking led: http://www.tomdesair.com/blog/2012/04/stop-the-blinking-wireless-led-in-linux/

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/wlan.conf
```

This will create a new file and open it in text editor. Add this text into file and save it:

```
options iwlwifi led_mode=1
```

Now restart your system or reload the WiFi driver using:

```
sudo -i
```

Give your password and then give:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I did what user271523 suggested and that fixed the blinking light. Now I just need to find a way to fix the issue of my wifi being slowed down

Comment: It's work for me even in debian 9, thank you